# Error in Claim based wcf service - The incoming policy could not be validated

Tags: .net, wcf, azure, claims-based-identity

I had developed Claim based WCF Service and the client application consuming wcf service.
but it throws an error while running client app - "The incoming policy could not be validated. For more information, please see the event log"

Here is the event log details: -

```
Incoming policy failed validation.  No valid claim elements were found in the policy XML.

Additional Information:
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.BuildMessage(InfoCardBaseException ie)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.TraceAndLogException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Diagnostics.InfoCardTrace.ThrowHelperError(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.InfoCardPolicy.Validate()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.PreProcessRequest()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.ClientUIRequest.PreProcessRequest()
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.Request.DoProcessRequest(String& extendedMessage)
   at Microsoft.InfoCards.RequestFactory.ProcessNewRequest(Int32 parentRequestHandle, IntPtr rpcHandle, IntPtr inArgs, IntPtr& outArgs)
```

I had gone through many SO question related to same, but nothing helped me.

Here is the config at wcf service side: - ([Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwHIh.png))

[image]

Here is the client config : -  ([Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LGG0.png))

[image]

here is how I am trying to call the service: -

[image]

Can anyone let me know what wrong I did here. May be I am not passing the token being received by STS to WCF Service. or may be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off CardSpace in you ChannelFactory:

```
_clientChannel = new ChannelFactory<IService>("WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService");
_clientChannel.ConfigureChannelFactory();
_clientChannel.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
```

SupportInteractive will turn off CardSpace.

If you still get an error, wrap the call to service with try catch block to catch the exception. See what's the error.

Also, turn on WCF tracing to see if error happens on WCF side. To turn on WCF Tracing:
http://stack247.wordpress.com/2013/05/23/wcf-tracing-and-diagnostic/